# How to resize partitions on a live server

Tags: linux, partitioning

I purchased a 240G remote server and it has no control panel to change the way the server is partitioned so my root folder is locked to 20G. I have looked through many pages of google results and finally caved to ask here.

```
Filesystem       Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev              16G     0   16G   0% /dev
tmpfs            3.2G  1.3M  3.2G   1% /run
/dev/sda2         20G  3.7G   15G  21% /
tmpfs             16G     0   16G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs             16G     0   16G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1        487M   79M  379M  18% /boot
/dev/sda3        200G   60M  190G   1% /home
```

I would like for the root to be larger than my home dir because thats where my programs are installed and use the space.

Comment: Did you purchase a physical machine? or are we talking about a remote server you have no physical access to? virtual maybe? Please [edit] the question and tell us more about the server.

Comment: It was a remote server and the panel does not provide a way to provision it the way I want.

Comment: Can you please add the output of `fdisk -l /dev/sda`? You may be able to, as suggested by @cybernard, resize (or remove) home, and simply extend root to a sensible size ...

Answer (score 2):

1. make a backup of **home**.
2. umount home.
3. Use a partitioning tool to shrink or delete and recreate a smaller **home**.
4. Create and mount a new partition  (parted is a command line tool)

If you can install vncserver and connect remotely you can install and use gparted.

Notes:  changing the root volume when its mounted is either not permitted or only permitted with a small number of file systems.

Alternatives:

pretend sda3 is home

```
    sda4 is new partition
```

5. mount /dev/sda4 /temp

Now say the /usr folder is causing your root to be full.

**As a precaution your should probably stop all or as many as possible running services.**

6. cp -r /usr /temp
7. mv usr usr.old
8. umount /temp
9. mount /dev/sda4 /usr

verify that the contents match

Restart all services, as needed

modify /etc/fstab and or /etc/mtab as needed so the new partition automatically mounts on reboot.

Alternatively if your distro has a GUI tool feel free to use that.

reboot

If everything is correct delete usr.old

Technically you could copy all the files to your new partition.  Then edit fstab and mtab so / points to /dev/sda4 and mount /dev/sda1 to a harmless folder like /useless.  After rebooting and verifying everything still works you could delete or not mount /useless or maybe reuse it for something else like /var or /var/log.

Here's some commands I got from the website I listed in the comments.

```
gparted
print
select /dev/sda3
#delete home
rm 3 (or whatever print tells you the partition number is
mkpart
primary
file system? whatever you want
start? don't know
end? don't know 20gb more that the start?
mkfs.ext4 /dev/sda3  (change the filesystem to whatever)
mkpart
primary
file system? whatever you want
start? don't know
end? don't know 100gb (or etc)more that the start?
mkfs.ext4 /dev/sda4  (change the filesystem to whatever)
```

Comment: I was trying to do it all via command line as to not install the bloated gui for linux

Comment: @Snipey Then use **parted** because its CLI.  Good luck figuring it out.

Comment: That's where I am at now. Massive headaches....

Comment: @Snipey  I am truly sorry to hear the pain your suffer, that is why I gave up and used the GUI.  In opensuse there is **yast disk** which is a CLI gui, but I don't know if your distro offers any tools like that.  Maybe this will help https://www.tecmint.com/parted-command-to-create-resize-rescue-linux-disk-partitions/  I googled it for you.